# NSPersistentCloudKitContainer and AppGroups

Tags: ios, swift, share, share-extension

can someone help me to find out how to use AppGroups with `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`?
I'm using CoreData in my iOS app and then want to access it in a share extension. My persistence looks like that:

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "MyApp")
        
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
    
}
```

How I need to add my "group.com.foo.myapp" App Group here to use it in both App and extension?

Comment: You make the [`localStoreLocation URL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit) the [AppGroup URL](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/core-data-app-extension-data-sharing/).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve the same problem and the following worked for me:

1. Create a `NSPersistentStoreDescription` with a url pointing to your app group
2. Set the store description's `cloudKitContainerOptions` to an an instance initialized with your cloud kit container identifier
3. Configure how you would like merges to be handled
4. Assign the store description to your `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`

```
init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
    container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "YourDataModel") // Replace with your data model name

    // 1. Configure for App Group
    let groupIdentifier = "group.com.example.MyApp" // Replace with your app group identifier
    let sharedContainerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: groupIdentifier)
    let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: sharedContainerURL!.appendingPathComponent("YourDataModel.sqlite")) // Replace with your data model name

    // 2. Configure for CloudKit
    let cloudKitContainerIdentifier = "YourCloudKitContainerID" // Replace with your CloudKit container identifier
    let cloudKitOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: cloudKitContainerIdentifier)
    storeDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = cloudKitOptions

    // 3. Handle merges
    storeDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
    container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true

    // 4. Assign store description
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]

    if inMemory {
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
    }
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
}
```